# How to Display Toast messages on LiveTV

Tags: google-tv

It was mentioned in one of the posts that we can show Toasts on Live Tv .
I am planning to develop a native GoogleTv app which fetches the Twitter updates and displays them as Toast messages while user is watching Live TV .
My question is - While invoking Toast function, which Activity  class reference do we need to provide inorder to display Toast messages on Live TV?

Please, do help me with this doubt.

Comment: Please do help me with this query

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html